# Find Distinct Values in XML Payload | XSL Mapping| SOA|BPEL

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, soa

I want to find distinct tag value in a XML Payload.

**Sample Payload**

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns0:execute xmlns:ns1="http://some.url" xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/connectivityproperties/REST/PostData_REQUEST/RESTOUTREQ" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/PostData_REQUEST/types">
   <ns1:processInterfaceLine>
      <ns1:interfaceLine>
         <ns1:customerOrderNumber>customerOrderNumber22387</ns1:customerOrderNumber>
         <ns1:metallurgistName>metallurgistName22388</ns1:metallurgistName>
         <ns1:jobNumber>jobNumber22389</ns1:jobNumber>
         <ns1:emsProgressInvoiceNumber>emsProgressInvoiceNumber22390</ns1:emsProgressInvoiceNumber>
      </ns1:interfaceLine>
      <ns1:interfaceLine>
         <ns1:customerOrderNumber>customerOrderNumber22388</ns1:customerOrderNumber>
         <ns1:metallurgistName>metallurgistName22388</ns1:metallurgistName>
         <ns1:jobNumber>jobNumber22389</ns1:jobNumber>
         <ns1:emsProgressInvoiceNumber>emsProgressInvoiceNumber22390</ns1:emsProgressInvoiceNumber>
      </ns1:interfaceLine>
      <ns1:interfaceLine>
         <ns1:customerOrderNumber>customerOrderNumber22387</ns1:customerOrderNumber>
         <ns1:metallurgistName>metallurgistName22388</ns1:metallurgistName>
         <ns1:jobNumber>jobNumber22389</ns1:jobNumber>
         <ns1:emsProgressInvoiceNumber>emsProgressInvoiceNumber223901</ns1:emsProgressInvoiceNumber>
      </ns1:interfaceLine>
   </ns1:processInterfaceLine>

</ns0:execute>
```

I want the output as below: I want the distinct values only based on **customerOrderNumber** tag.Not the entire paylod.

**Desired Output::**

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns0:execute xmlns:ns1="http://some.url" xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/connectivityproperties/REST/PostData_REQUEST/RESTOUTREQ" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/PostData_REQUEST/types">
   <ns1:processInterfaceLine>
      <ns1:interfaceLine>
         <ns1:customerOrderNumber>customerOrderNumber22387</ns1:customerOrderNumber>
         <ns1:metallurgistName>metallurgistName22388</ns1:metallurgistName>
         <ns1:jobNumber>jobNumber22389</ns1:jobNumber>
         <ns1:emsProgressInvoiceNumber>emsProgressInvoiceNumber22390</ns1:emsProgressInvoiceNumber>
      </ns1:interfaceLine>
      <ns1:interfaceLine>
         <ns1:customerOrderNumber>customerOrderNumber22388</ns1:customerOrderNumber>
         <ns1:metallurgistName>metallurgistName22388</ns1:metallurgistName>
         <ns1:jobNumber>jobNumber22389</ns1:jobNumber>
         <ns1:emsProgressInvoiceNumber>emsProgressInvoiceNumber22390</ns1:emsProgressInvoiceNumber>
      </ns1:interfaceLine>
</ns0:execute>
```

Comment: Start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html Come back if you run into a specific problem.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you share the mapping as per our requirement.